# What is the proof of this formula for selecting one or more objects of three different kinds?

Tags: combinatorics

I found this formula in a website: Number of ways in which one or more objects can be selected out of $S_1$ alike objects of one kind, $S_2$ alike objects of second kind and $S_3$ alike objects of third kind $= (S_1 + 1)(S_2 + 1)(S_3 + 1) - 1$.

Where did they get this from? Does this use the concept of multinomial theorem? How is it derived?

Comment: Pick how many objects of the first type you take.  You have the options of having taken $0,1,2,3,\dots,S_1$ for a total of $S_1+1$ options.  Then pick how many objects of the second type.  You will similarly have $S_2+1$ options, and then $S_3+1$ options for the third type.  Apply [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).  Then recognize that one of those results corresponded to having selected none of the first, second, or third types.  Since we wanted to have picked *one or more*, we didn't want to pick only zero, so correct the count.

Comment: No, this has absolutely nothing to do with the multinomial theorem.  It is more fundamental, having relied on the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) and the [rule of sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum).

Comment: @JMoravitz Post it as an answer! It makes sense to me!

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.